# Assigning an array output in the email body variable

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-3.4, jmail, email-template

I have been working on this class for days with no luck or results.

I'm trying to insert variable in the email body that contains a function that iterates through an array. The variable that has problems is the `$yearFunction` that calls `cleaningArrays()` method.

I have tested by inserting an `exit()` right after calling the `cleaningArrays()` and I could the data through the array is correct, but it won't just get passed down to the body section.

When an email is sent it just comes as blank no data from the `$yearFunction` variable.

```
// No direct access.
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

// Include dependancy of the main controller form class
jimport('joomla.application.component.controllerform');
JForm::addFormPath(JPATH_COMPONENT_ADMINISTRATOR . '/models/forms');

class VifBadgesControllerBadges extends JControllerForm
{
    protected $yearBadgeArray;
    protected $moduleBadgeArray;
    protected $otherBadgeArray;
    protected $yearBadges;
    protected $moduleBadges;
    protected $otherBadges;
    protected $recipientName;
    protected $recipientEmail;
    protected $message;
    protected $badgeEarner;
    protected $yearFunction;    

    public function cleaningArrays($list)
    {
        for ($k=0; $k < count($list); $k++)
        {
            echo $list[$k];
        }

        return ;
    }


    public function submit()
    {
        // Check for request forgeries.
        JRequest::checkToken() or jexit(JText::_('JINVALID_TOKEN'));

        // Initialize variables.
        $app = JFactory::getApplication();
        $mail = &JFactory::getMailer();
        $user = JFactory::getUser();
        $redirectUrl = JRoute::_('index.php/', false);

        $postData = $app->input->post;
        $this->recipientEmail = $postData->get('email', '', 'STRING');
        $this->recipientName = $postData->get('name', '', 'STRING');
        $this->message = $postData->get('message', '', 'STRING');
        $this->badgeEarner = $postData->get('badgeEarner', '', '');
        $yearBadgeArray = $postData->get('yearBadgeData', '', '');
        $moduleBadgeArray = $postData->get('moduleBadgeData', '', '');
        $otherBadgeArray = $postData->get('otherBadgeData', '', '');

        $this->yearBadgeArray= unserialize(base64_decode($yearBadgeArray));
        $this->moduleBadgeArray= unserialize(base64_decode($moduleBadgeArray));
        $this->otherBadgeArray= unserialize(base64_decode($otherBadgeArray));

        $yearFunction = function()
        {
            $badge = [];

            foreach ($this->yearBadgeArray as $yearBadge)
            {
                $badge[] = $yearBadge[2][1];
            }

            $this->cleaningArrays($badge);

        };

        $body = "<div style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;'>
        <p>Hi ".$this->recipientName.",</p>
        <p>".$this->badgeEarner." has earned digital badges for completing a PD modules in VIF's Learning Center and wants to share the details with you!</p>
        <p><strong>Message from ".$this->badgeEarner."</strong> " .$this->message."</p>
        <p><strong>Year Badges:</strong></p>

        <p>".$yearFunction()."</p>

        <hr style='border:0px;color:rgb(237,237,235);min-height:1px;width:525px;background-color:rgb(237,237,235)' />
        <div style='font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;text-align:center;font-size:10px;color:rgb(102,102,102)'>
        <p>This email was sent to Andrew from Community.</p><p>2015</p></div>";

        $senderEmail = $user->email;
        $senderName = $user->name;
        $sender = array($senderEmail, $senderName);

        $mail->ClearAddresses();
        $mail->setSender($sender);
        $mail->addRecipient($this->recipientEmail);
        $mail->Encoding = 'base64';
        $mail->setSubject(JText::_($this->badgeEarner.' Shared a Digital Badge'));
        $mail->IsHTML(true);
        $mail->setBody($body);

        $send = $mail->Send();


    }
}
```

Comment: On a side note, don't use `JRequest` as it's deprecated

Comment: On the actual topic, have you set error reporting to `development` on your Global Configuration? Also, have you tried returning the result of your anonymous function like so: `return $this->cleaningArrays($badge);` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it thanks for my co-worker Simon. So what I did is I removed the cleaningArrays() method, and re-wrote my anonymous function like below by adding the **implode()** method:

```
$yearBadgesFunction = function()
    {
        $badge = [];

        foreach ($this->yearBadgeArray as $yearBadge)
        {
            $badge[] = $yearBadge[2][1];
        }

        $badgeDataSet = implode(" ", $badge);

        return $badgeDataSet;
    };
```